# Quaternions to Euler angles vs Euler angles

Tags: quaternions

I am working on Quaternions and Euler angles with a gyroscope and dedrifting methods. What I have done is to calculate the angles with both methods. However, I noticed that when I used Euler angles and the same dedrifting method the result was more accurate (in comparison with the real rotation) against the Quaternions transformed to Euler angles. I transformed the Quaternions to Euler angles for visualization purposes.

So, my questions are:

1) Quaternions present higher error because have been transformed to Euler angles? Do they accumulate errors due to the transformation?

2) Is there a possibility Quaternions to produce higher errors than Euler angles because of the integration of the quaternions derivative?

q_dot = 1/2*q x Ω (where x is quaternion multiplication)